# Log formatting using awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Log file has thousands of lines generated in below format..

```
05:34:11,447 DEBUG [com.ibm.cmps.beer.web.action.BlastApp]  deliveryConstant FTP is completed
```

To simplify, My Log text file has data in following format

```
d1 o1 c1 message1
d1 o1 c1 message2
d1 o1 c1 message3
d1 o1 c2 message4
d1 o1 c2 message5
d1 o1 c3 message6
d1 o1 c4 message7
d1 o1 c5 message8
```

To display only classnames(c1,c2,...) and messages, I use below command to drop column 1 & 2-

```
awk '{$1=$2="";print $0}' file.log
```

As log file is very large, I want to filter log in below format-

```
c1  message1
    message2
    message3
c2  message4
    message5
c3  message6
c4  message7
c5  message8
```

I wish to skip repeated class names or replace it with space.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, what did you get, and where are you stuck?  You need to know the `printf()` command reasonably well.  What happens if the different classes are different lengths; how should the indentation work?

Comment: I have tried, but not very much familiar with awk usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '!a[$3]{printf $3; a[$3]=1} {print "\t"$4}' File
```

Output:

```
c1      message1
        message2
        message3
c2      message4
        message5
c3      message6
c4      message7
c5      message8
```

Comment: Probably better to use just a regular variable (`last_class`, whatever) to store the previous class value instead of a key in an associative array.  With large input, this is going to continue using memory for each new class, which will also get slower over time as the associative array fills up.  Overwriting a variable each time would use roughly constant memory. Tabs also may not align properly. I'd suggest something like this `last_c == $3{ $3="  " } { print $3,$4; last_c=$3 }`  Could use a for loop to populate the cleared-out repeated $3s so they're the same width as the original.